# use command lines inside a perl script

Tags: perl

I know there is a command you can run in the command like this

```
perl -p -i -e 's/oldtext/newttext/g' file
```

I was just wondering if you could use the same command inside the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the script equivalent of that one liner would be the following:

```
local @ARGV = 'file';
local $^I = '';
while (<>) {
    s/oldtext/newttext/g;
    print;
}
```

Just search for [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for details.

Comment: just a quick question, is there some type of error handling if it can't find the old text?

Comment: This is the literal equivalent if your one liner, so no.  What would you count as an error though?  If it doesn't find oldtext in a line, it simply won't replace anything.  This seems the proper behavior to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it takes a slightly different form though:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $filename = $ARGV[0] 
   or die "Must supply filename";

my $file;
{ # read the file into a single scalar
   open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
      or die "Can't open '$filename': $!\n";
   local $/;
   $file = <$fh>;
}

# apply your substitution
$file =~ s/oldtext/newtext/g;

{ # overwrite existing file with changes
   open(my $fh, '>', $filename)
      or die "Can't create '$filename': $!\n";
   print {$fh} $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl doesn't understand bourne shell, but you can launch a shell to execute it for you using `system`. (For more complicated needs, modules such as IPC::Run3 and IPC::Run are very useful.)

```
system('sh', '-c', q{perl -p -i -e 's/oldtext/newttext/g' file});
```

The alternative syntax of `system` allows you to simplify the above to the following:

```
system(q{perl -p -i -e 's/oldtext/newttext/g' file});
```

But! Instead of telling a shell to launch `perl`, though, you could launch `perl` directly.

```
system('perl', '-p', '-i', '-e', 's/oldtext/newttext/g', 'file');
```

But! Instead of launching a second `perl`, you could merge the two programs together.

```
local @ARGV = 'file';
local $^I   = '';
while (<>) {
   s/oldtext/newttext/g;
   print;
}
```